# Unable to install new packages with pub command

Tags: flutter

The following is the excerpt from my pubspec.yaml file. I have added new dependency for shared preferences. when i do command pub get i get the error

> Package secondapp requires SDK version >=2.7.0 <3.0.0 but the current SDK is 1.10.1.

I am able to resolve this by adding proper path to my dart installation. But after doing this, the flutter version error is coming.

My yaml file :

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter,


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
```

I am unable to add the dependency. What settings am i missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the result of `flutter doctor` to your post ?

Comment: The sdk error i am able to resolve but now another error is coming. i have attached studio screenshot of error and doctor screenshot. kindly check

Comment: i am able to resolve it. just removing the comma after flutter did it. thanks